# Respuesta undefined al hacer map => Promise.all => map => Promise.all ¿Tienen idea que estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: nodejs

Tengo una función, `getComments` la cual toma un id, mapea x id un comentario, uso un promise.all para esperar la finalización de la función y vuelvo a repetir este proceso (map => promisee.all) con el resultado de el primer mapeo, el problema es que al recibir el username, siempre figura undefined. Desde la función que llama getUserById, la respuesta es la que debería al mostrarla por consola.

```
async function getComments(req: Request, res: Response) {
  let response = await PostComment.getPostsCommets(req.params.post_id);

  //@ts-ignore;
  let commentsData = [];
  if (typeof response != 'undefined') {
    const promises = response.map(async (comment) => {
      //@ts-ignore
      let aux = await Comment.getComments(comment.comment_id);
      console.log(aux);
      return aux;
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((result) => {
        commentsData = result;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('There was an error:', error);
      });

    //@ts-ignore
    const promisesUsername = commentsData.map(async (comment) => {
      let username = await User.getUserById(comment.creator_id);
      return {
        id: comment.id,
        content: comment.content,
        username: username,
      };
    });

    Promise.all(promisesUsername).then((final) => {
      res.json(final);
    });
  }
}
```

Función que llama

```
async function getUserById(id: number) {
  try {
    if (id == null) {
      Promise.reject({ en: 'You forgot to send an id, silly' });
    }

    let connection = await openConnection();

    if (connection instanceof Error || typeof connection === 'undefined') {
      Promise.reject({ en: 'Failed to connect' });
    } else {
      const [results, fields] = await connection.execute(
        'SELECT * FROM users WHERE  id = ?',
        [id],
      );
      console.log('------------------------------');
      console.log(results);
      //@ts-ignore
      console.log(results[0].username);
      console.log('------------------------------');
      if (Array.isArray(results) && results.length !== 0) {
        //@ts-ignore
        Promise.resolve(results[0].username);
      } else {
        Promise.reject('The user does not exist');
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando llamas a `Promise.all(promises).then((result) => {})` no estás esperando a que acabe, y luego ya usas `commentsData`, pero no has esperado a que procese.
Debes esperar que `commentsData` se llene antes de intentar trabajar con el.
Puedes usar `await` para esperarlo así:

```
async function getComments(req: Request, res: Response) {
  let response = await PostComment.getPostsCommets(req.params.post_id);

  //@ts-ignore;
  let commentsData = [];
  if (typeof response != 'undefined') {
    const promises = response.map(async (comment) => {
      //@ts-ignore
      let aux = await Comment.getComments(comment.comment_id);
      console.log(aux);
      return aux;
    });

    //Esperas que procese usando `await`
    let commentsData; 
    try {
      commentsData = await Promise.all(promises);
    } catch((error) => {
        console.error('There was an error:', error);
      });

    //@ts-ignore
    const promisesUsername = commentsData.map(async (comment) => {
      let username = await User.getUserById(comment.creator_id);
      return {
        id: comment.id,
        content: comment.content,
        username: username,
      };
    });

    Promise.all(promisesUsername).then((final) => {
      res.json(final);
    });
  }
}
```